# file_get_contents() ignores hosts

Tags: php, vagrant, localhost, file-get-contents

I've had this problem two times already and I was unable to find the answer on Internet.

I've got a local, development apache server set up in vagrant machine, which serves my website correctly. I also have my hosts set up properly in /etc/hosts and I can access the development website easily with any browser. But when I try to get the contents of a processed php script (with file_get_contents() ), to convert this later into a pdf file, the function ignores my hosts settings and tries to find this site on Internet. It doesn't exist as the site isn't live yet.

Is there a way to make file_get_contents comply with my hosts settings?

My php script:

```
$html = file_get_contents(get_template_directory_uri(). "/pdf-template.php");
```

My hosts settings:

```
192.168.56.123  site.com
192.168.56.123  www.site.com
```

Comment: PHP does a DNS lookup and DNS lookups do not use a hosts file. Ever.

Comment: Is there a way to override this? @CharlotteDunois

Comment: If you update the PHP source code to first look into the hosts file and then re-compile PHP, sure. Otherwise no.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_contents($url, $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1', $referer = 'http://www.google.com/') {
    $header[0] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    if(curl_errno($curl)){
        http_response_code(500);
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    return $content;
}

// setting up dns cache
$ch = curl_init('http://site.localhost/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, ["site.localhost:80:127.0.0.1"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);


// getting content
get_contents('http://site.localhost/')
```

That code works for me instead of /etc/hosts.